# Green blinking star above main hand weapon, no new items, bug?

Tags: diablo-iii-console

I have a green blinking star above the main hand weapon (Diablo 3 on Xbox One).

Typically I would think this meant that I had picked up some new item without inspecting it, but it continues to be there even though I've sold all the items except the equipped one.

I tried unequipping the item, and reequipping it, but the start continues to blink.

Does it signify something else?

Or is it just a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to a [topic on the forum](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/14058717022), this star means that you have a legendary item that you can equip in that slot. It may also be that this legendary is in your chest. Quote from the forum:

> They are in my storage chest. Even if they are in your chest, they
>   still put the star on your character's inventory, even if you are not
>   carrying them!